# Getting all PFGeoPoints that are within the visible map view

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I am using Parse within my iOS App (using Swift). Now I have a bunch of PFGeoPoints with long and latitude. If I now show the map, I would like to show each point as an annotation, that is viewable within the visible map.

I thought about something like this:
`query.whereKey("location", nearGeoPoint:userGeoPoint)`
where nearGeoPoint is the middle of the visible map, but this seems to be dirty.

Is there a better solution for this?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Got that working using this:

```
let swOfSF = PFGeoPoint(latitude:37.708813, longitude:-122.526398)
let neOfSF = PFGeoPoint(latitude:37.822802, longitude:-122.373962)
var query = PFQuery(className:"Car")
query.whereKey("location", withinGeoBoxFromSouthwest:swOfSF, toNortheast:neOfSF)
var visibleCars = query.findObjects()
```

where swOfSF is the most south west point of San Francisco and neOfSF is the most Norh East of San Francisco

Cheers